# Gauss Jordan over GF(p) - If there are infinitely many solutions, return any of them

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra

so for something I'm doing I need to find a solution to a system of linear equations modulo some prime, which I've implemented with Gauss-Jordan.  The thing is, my implementation at the moment only works given that a solution exists: if there are no solutions, or infinitely many solutions, I'm just unable to find a pivot and I return a flag.  The thing is, rather than just say "infinitely many solutions", I was hoping for a way to return *any* solution, hopefully somewhat near to the O(n^3) of Gauss-Jordan.

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Comment: Probably need to ask on math.stackexchange.com. Another possibility is to ask on the sage-support forum for the mathematical software Sage; I think people there will have suggestions or maybe even an existing function or program for this.

Comment: Noted, I will do that.  Thanks.